# stored procedure parameter declared as NULL but parameter property in sql showing no default in production(Only)

Tags: sql-server

I have stored procedure working in development and declare parameter as NULL. The same procedure moved to production but showing as not null parameter. Pls find the images of comparison between DEV and PROD [image]

Comment: A SP parameter does not have a default value, unless specified: it is likely the production SP definition is 'wrong' / was made 'wrong' during the move. SSMS will happily generate a 'CREATE TO' script that can be used to see the *actual* definition, in a textual form (pro-tip: text >> images of text). Also, sometimes the SSMS cache/views get out of date. Ensure these are refreshed: also see 'CREATE TO' above.

Comment: i tried checking the create to script for the procedure in production and declared parameter as NULL.

Comment: can you able to view the procedure script in production and recheck whether NULL is in place?

Comment: I dont have permission to Modify the SP. But for the Admin user showing parameter as default NULL. My user show NO Default NULL

Comment: @chandrsekar.L.S. Is it *two* SP's with the same name in different schemas (or DB instances)? This is not a per-user setting. A SP has default values or it does not.

Comment: I dont have Modify option due to the security constrain on production. For admin user accepting null values.